# Android Studio 2.2.2 InvalidPathException

Tags: java, android

The problem is that AS cannot recognize the cyrillic characters in path.

```
InvalidPathException: Illegal char  at index 9: C:\Users\??????\.android\avd\startandroid.avd
```

How can I resolve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the directory where the AVDs are saved.
So you can create an folder somewhere with no cyrillic characters in the path.

To change the AVD-path you have to add the environment variable `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` with the path to your new folder.

The Dialog can be found under `Control Panel --> System --> Advanced System Settings (on the left side) --> Environment Variables`.